# Do I have to reload app.js every time I make a small change?

Tags: node.js

When I start up my application in node.js

```
node app.js
```

and then make a change in app.js file, I have to exit node.js and restart it in order for this change to show up in my browser.

Is node.js caching the file at startup? Is there a way to avoid this, at least in development mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modules are cached when they are required. Take a look at http://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor as a solution to your problem.

Comment: how to run nodemon on windows. ?

Comment: No! Actually I figured it out. just go to the directory where your nodejs files are stored and run npm command to install files. 

Regards

Answer (score 5):

[nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) is built to do exactly what you need:

> Monitor for any changes in your node.js application and automatically restart the server - perfect for development

Comment: Thats perfect solution, it helped me. I think this answer should have been accepted.

Answer (score 3):

There is a package named **node-dev**. It will restart the server once you change the code (while application is running) and save it.

```
npm install node-dev
```

Comment: Yes the link is https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev. And use this command to run the app "node-dev foo.js". That solved my issue :)